# Why isn't my interval function updating the page text?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a html and JavaScript clock, but the setInterval function in JS is not updating the text in html every second.

```js
const time = new Date();
const time_text = document.getElementById("time");
var hours = time.getHours();
var minutes = time.getMinutes();
var seconds = time.getSeconds();

function displayTime() {
  time_text.innerHTML = String(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
}

setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"><div>
```

Comment: It's not updating because your code never changes the time values.

Comment: That is, you're not updating `hours`, `minutes`, or `seconds`, so the text _is_ updating but it just uses the same values each time. Also, don't compose strings this way, use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): ```timeText.textContent = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;```. And on that note: stick to JS naming conventions, so variables and functions use lowerCamelCase, there are no underscores in variables or functions in JS, that's PHP/Python. And of course: use `.textContent` if you're setting text =)

Comment: Protip: Ask yourself why you used `const` in some cases and `var` in others. These can all be the former.

Comment: Thank you, I've only been coding for maybe a few months of JS so it's still a learning process. How would I go about updating the time?

Comment: Move the `var hours = ... ` etc and the `new Date()` line to **inside** the timer callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable must be initalized/set again inside the function, so that each time your function is called, the latest time value gets initialized.

```js
const timeText = document.getElementById("time");

function displayTime() {
    const time = new Date();
    const hours = time.getHours();
    const minutes = time.getMinutes();
    const seconds = time.getSeconds();

    timeText.textContent = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`
}

setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"><div>
```

Here, each time the `displayTime` function is being called, the latest time values go into the variables, and hence the content gets changed to the latest time value.

Comment: `document.getElementById("time");` never changes for the lifetime of this page. You _really_ don't want to be calling that every 1-second interval. Declare it _before_ the displayTime function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var time = new Date();
var timeText = document.getElementById("time");
var hours = time.getHours();
var minutes = time.getMinutes();
var seconds = time.getSeconds();

function displayTime() {
    time = new Date()
    hours = time.getHours();
    minutes = time.getMinutes();
    seconds = time.getSeconds();
    timeText.textContent = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`
}

setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
```

Comment: As @Pointy pointed out, *move* the declarations as well, ie including the `var ...` part.   You're creating *global variables* rather than *scoped variables* - I'll let you research the reason global variables aren't good, now that you have the terminology (obviously doesn't matter for such as small amount of code, but better to get into good habits now).

Comment: The only variable you need outside of `function displayTime()` is your _timeText_ and it could be a `const timeText = document.getElementById("time");`  The others — time, hours, minutes, seconds — can be declared _inside_ displayTime() and, since they don't change after being set within the function call they can also be declared `const`